# copying output from one R session to another R session

Tags: r, output

I am having 2 R sessions now working on one vector in each of the session with slight difference inside, say:

session1: `temp1 <- c(1:10)`

session2: `temp2 <- c(2:11)`

I want to copy the `temp1` from session1 into session2 and do a `%in%`, but I don't want use `print(temp1)` in session1, `ctrl-c` it, manually modify the output and then `ctrl-v` it in session2.

I have seen someone using a generic function that create an output in the R session, then I `ctrl-c` the output directly and `ctrl-v` it in another R session and the object is already there. But I can't remember the function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to pass the data from one session to another. That means you need to (efficiently) serialize the data.

The easiest, by far, will be a `save()` followed by  a `load()`.  If you want to be fancy, you can use sockets instead of files -- see `help(connections)` for details

Comment: yea, I know this is possible but isn't there a function that (something like `cat` an object into a bunch of lines) directly copy-paste the output to another session will give you back the object? I saw it somewhere in stackoverflow but forget it, so wondering if anyone knows

Comment: `dput` is the function your comment is looking for, but that that is not what your question appears to be asking

Comment: Yes -- `dput()` works well for tiny objects. But one day you will want to pass _real_ data around for which the _serialization to printable ascii_ is way too inefficient. Enter `save()` / `load()`.

Comment: yea, I won't use `dput` for a big dataframe, just a vector with maybe 100 strings.